# Script to update all git sub-modules path using git commands (not via editing .gitmodules file)

Tags: git, git-bash

I got numerous sumbmodules for my git project.
.gitmodules looks like that

```
[submodule "one"]
    path = one
    url = ../one
    branch = master
[submodule "two"]
    path = two
    url = ../two
    branch = master
[submodule "three"]
    path = three
    url = ../three
    branch = master
```

Submodule list in unknown, I need way to change all submodules path, add prefix for directory name, so my .gitmodule file will look like that:

```
[submodule "one"]
    path = new_one
    url = ../one
    branch = master
[submodule "two"]
    path = new_two
    url = ../two
    branch = master
[submodule "three"]
    path = new_three
    url = ../three
    branch = master
```

I am using that command to change the path `git config --file=.gitmodules submodule.[Submodule].path [new_path]`, I need way to it for all submodules.

The logic for the solution as I see it:

- Get all submodules list
- For-each submodule: -> Get current path -> Set new path

Thanks

Comment: If it's just about updating the `.gitmodules` file, edit the file right away : search & replace with your favorite editor (`path = ` to `path = new_`), or use `sed`

Comment: If you have some other need, please describe your use case with more details. For example : I didn't get what you mean with : "Since submodules list is continuously generating"

Comment: editing .gitmodules is not preferred option, I prefer to use git commands.

Comment: academic purposes apart, the final word in git is given by the gitmodules file. Do you wish to create an automation script to run git commands to achieve your goal? If so, please state it in the question

Comment: Your question really looks like "I want to move a list of submodules within my repository", however this intention is not explicitly written in your question : for example you describe how you want to manipulate path entries in your `.gitmodules` file, then you describe a function which iterates on each submodule and mentions their paths, yet the "Set new path" sentence could be interpreted in different ways. I still hope my answer was the one you were looking for. Happy hacking !

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the command to relocate an existing submodule is not `git submodule [smth]`, it simply is :

```
git mv [submodule] [new_path]
```

This command does both :

- effectively rename the `submodule/` folder (and moves it to another directory if `new_path` indicates so),
- update the `.gitmodules` file in your repo